# Regex issue with replace simple string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using Regex replace as below :

```
string test = "[abc] Sends the employee mail. [twist] Sends the employee mail.";
test = Regex.Replace(test, "[twist]", "hello");
```

And the result is coming as :

```
test = "[abc] Sendhello hellohe employee mahellol. [hellohellohellohellohello] Sendhello hellohe employee mahellol."
```

**Where as it should just replace [twist] string with hello.**

What is going wrong here.

Comment: Try using one of the [many](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) [RegEx](http://rubular.com/) [parsers](http://regexhero.net/tester/) [out](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) [there](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/regular-expression-tools-resources/) first. Will explain it for you instantly in most cases. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the brackets (at least the opening one). Change

```
"[twist]"
```

to

```
"\\[twist\\]"
```

or, using [a verbatim literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to avoid the double `\`,

```
@"\[twist\]"
```

`[twist]` is interpreted as any of the t, w, i, s or t character and any of them is replaced by the `hello` string.

Comment: or `@"\[twist\]"` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Replace(test,"\[twist\]","hello")

Answer (score 0):

As additional useful informations, you could escape the `[` as `[[]`, so

```
"[[]twist]"
```

or you could

```
"\\x5btwist]"
```

where `\x5b` is the ascii code of `[`. Note that you need to escape the `\` of `\x5b` because otherwise `"\x5b" == "["` (the C# makes the string replacement). By escaping it instead it's the Regex that "receives" the `\x5b` and considers it as a `[`. Clearly you could disable escape sequences expansion by using the `@`

```
@"\x5btwist]"
```